# When i look at freeswitch logs the following errors are seen

Tags: centos, erlang, centos7, freeswitch, kazoo

mod_kazoo unimplemented feature error in freeswitch logs

This is for a `centos7` server with `RabbitMQ 3.3, bigcouch 3.3.6, kazoo 4.3.` I tried building and linking these but got the following errors while adding freeswitch , kamalio and ecallmgr.

> [ERR] kazoo_node.c:996 Recieved mod_kazoo message for unimplemented
>   feature (ensure you are using Kazoo v2.14+): json_api
>
> [warning] |00000000000|ecallmgr_fs_nodes:681(<0.5448.0>)  unable to
>   start node freeswitch@server.local handlers:
>   {{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,'freeswitch@server.local_node',{'EXIT',{function_clause,[{kz_json,decode,[badarg],[{file,"src/kz_json.erl"},{line,169}]},
>
> [error] |0000000000|Undefined:Undefined(<0.5453.0>)  Supervisor
>   'freeswitch@server.local'had child'freeswitch@server.local_node' 
>   started with ecallmgr_fs_node:start_link('freeswitch@server.local',
>   [{client_version,<<"mod_kazoo v1.4.0-1">>},

Answer (score 0):

Looks as you use latest FreeSwitch 1.8 or 1.10 branch.
With kazoo 4.3 compatible FreeSwitch 1.8.5.
Next FreeSwitch releases requires kazoo 5.0 (master branch).